# How to do the web application testing by capturing JSON request and response using selenium webdriver?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I wanted to test Salesforce Lightning application by capturing JSON request and response with Selenium WebDriver or any?

Is there any way to do it, if so how?

Comment: Are you looking to send JSON requests yourself, or capture the JSON requests that are being sent by another application?

Comment: Do you have access to change the endpoints which the application is pointing to? Potentially a Mock Server or MITM would be a good start. If you're looking to just test raw JSON request/response SoapUI or POSTman would be better

Comment: Yes, there is a way to do it. "It is a matter of simple programming" (TM) :-)

Comment: Selenium Webdriver is the wrong choice for capturing JSON requests and responses.

Answer (score 2):

You should consider other tools to test it as Selenium is browser automation framework and you seem to be talking about [REST API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer). Selenium limitations are:

- You don't have control of [HTTP Headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers), you will need at least [Content-Type](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/4_Content-Type.html)
- It will be tricky to send non-GET requests (POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.)

So the options are in:

1. Use underlying Selenium client libraries. Under the hood Selenium uses [JSON](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/JsonWireProtocol) requests so if you have enough programming knowledge you should be able to manually construct relevant HTTP Requests with JSON payload and parse responses
2. Use alternative tool. The most most popular are:

   - [SoapUI](https://www.soapui.org/)
   - [RESTClient](http://restclient.net/)
   - [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/)
   - [Apache JMeter](https://blazemeter.com/blog/testing-soaprest-web-services-using-jmeter)

Comment: I intermix API and UI test scenarios.  My (cucumber) scenario '@Before' hook checks the scenario tags and if '@api' is among them then it skips the selenium start up code (i.e. no browser instance is created). Ditto in the '@After' hook. The only harm of not using the '@api' tag is that a selenium browser session is needlessly created. In the aggregate it adds up so best to use '@api'.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using java take a look at Jayway's [rest-assured](https://github.com/jayway/rest-assured). I have a quick (well for me) start project [here](https://github.com/mikejramsey56/cuc_jav_webdriver). Look for tags @rest or @api.

If you are using Ruby then [HTTParty](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/its-time-to-httparty) is a very simple way to accomplish the same.  I have a local project (using [Strongloop](https://strongloop.com/) to generate a local test target) but I haven't pushed it yet. There are many alternatives in the ruby world for API testing.

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't know what language you're using, I'm going to assume Java.  These ideas should be language independent, though.

Selenium cannot do this.  What you're describing is either the job of a proxy server, or the job of an http library.  When you encounter situations like this, it isn't uncommon to introduce additional libraries to use alongside Selenium.

If you wanted to explore the proxy option to intercept incoming and outgoing traffic for analysis.  You can set up Selenium to run through a proxy quite easily:

With chrome:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArgument("--proxy-server", "localhost:1234");
```

With firefox:

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();

profile.setPreference("network.proxy.type", 1);
profile.setPreference("network.proxy.http", "localhost");
profile.setPreference("network.proxy.port", 1234);
```

With this, you can use whatever proxy you want, whether it's a programmatically driven one integrated into your tests, or an external one such as CharlesProxy.

An alternative to proxy servers is to not use Selenium at all when you need to send requests and analyze their response (This isn't often possible unless the item under test is an API call).  I would suggest using a library such as HttpUnit which will let you send raw http requests out and receive their responses.

If you're interested in learning more about why Selenium doesn't allow you to view http traffic directly, this may be an interesting read (though focused specifically towards viewing http status codes): http://jimevansmusic.blogspot.com/2012/07/webdriver-y-u-no-have-http-status-codes.html